# CakePHP show buttons based on ACL

Tags: cakephp, acl, cakephp-2.2

I have a ACL system setup on my application in CakePHP 2.2.3.

I wanted to know how can I make cake when is baking the models to automatically show commands(buttons) only to the groups that have access to it?

If it is possible I need a efficient solution too because I am creating a big application.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Check out `MenuBuilder` to define and call/build pre-defined menus based on ACL setups.

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/rifat/2011/05/08/menubuilder_v1_0_1

I'm working on a project that was handed to me using this setup. It appeared to work right out of the box on CakePHP 2.1.2. I had to override part of my AuthComponent to get a HABTM group/permissions model to work however.

QUICK EDIT: The author's github is linked from that page for the most up to date. There seems to be enough support on that page and google to troubleshoot most issues.

Comment: take a look at this link please